# Evitar que se borren los datos introducidos en el formulario al recargar la pagina

Tags: mvc, razor

Tengo un formulario donde el usuario puede hacer una búsqueda filtrada de libros. el problema es que cuando se vuelve a recargar la `View` con los resultados de la búsqueda en la `tabla`, desaparece lo que el usuario escribió anteriormente en los `input`. Necesito que si por ejemplo el usuario escribe como nombre de libro "el principito", autor:"xx" cuando me trae los resultados, esos datos sigan mostrándose en los `input`.

Aca el formulario.

```html
@model List<Librery_MVC.Models.Libro>

@using (Html.BeginForm("userListarLibros", "Usser", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Nombre de libro</label>
    @*<div class="input-group inputFiltros">*@
    @Html.TextBox("bookName", "", new { @class = "form-control inputFiltros", id = "txtBuscar", placeholder = "Ingrese nombre del libro", maxlength = "80" })
    @*</div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Autor</label>
        <select name="ddlAutor" class="form-control inputFiltros" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
            <option></option>
            @foreach (Autor item in autorList)
            {
                <option value=@item.IdAutor>@item.Nombre</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Categoria</label>
        <select name="ddlCategory" class="form-control inputFiltros" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
            <option></option>
            @foreach (Categoria item in categoryList)
            {
                <option value=@item.IdCategoria>@item.Nombre</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default inputFiltros" value="Filtrar" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

Y aca la tabla donde muestro los resultados

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-primary mt-5 table-bordered" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Autor</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" style="color:red">
                        No Match any document
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (Libro item in Model)
                {

                    autor = sa.getAutor(item.IdAutor);
                    editorial = es.GetEditorial(item.IdEditorial);
                    category = cs.getCategoria(item.IdCategoria);

                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <input type="submit" name="btn_mostrar" value="mostrar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            @Html.ActionLink("Comprar", "#", "Usser", new { idLibro = item.IdLibro }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Baja", "BajaLibro", "Home", new { idLibro = item.IdLibro }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger", onclick = "return confirmation();" })*@
                        </th>
                        <th>@item.IdLibro</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">@item.Nombre</th>
                        <th>@autor.Nombre</th>
                        <th>@category.Nombre</th>
                        <th class="col-md-3"><textarea rows="4" cols="40" readonly>@item.Descripcion</textarea></th>
                        <th>@item.Precio</th>
                        <th><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

este es el controlador

```html
public ActionResult userListarLibros()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            ViewBag.Email = Request.Form["email"];
            LibroService ls = new LibroService();//es lo mismo
            AutorService sa = new AutorService();

            bool hayBookName = false;
            bool hayAutor = false;
            bool hayCategory = false;
            String consulta = "";

            String bookName = Request.Form["bookName"];
            String autor = Request.Form["ddlAutor"];
            String cat = Request.Form["ddlCategory"];

            int idAutor = 0;
            int idCategory = 0;

            if(bookName != null)
                hayBookName = true;

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(autor))
            {
                hayAutor = true;
                idAutor = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlAutor"]);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cat))
            {
                hayCategory = true;
                idCategory = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlCategory"]);
            }

            // hay nombre de libro autor y categoria
            if (hayBookName && hayAutor && hayCategory)
                consulta = "select * from libros where nombre Like '%" + bookName + "%'" + " and idAutor = " + idAutor + " and idCategoria = " + idCategory;

            //hay nombre de libro y autor pero no hay categoria
            else if (hayBookName && hayAutor && hayCategory == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where nombre Like '%" + bookName + "%'" + " and idAutor = " + idAutor;

            //hay nombre de libro y categoria pero no hay autor
            else if (hayBookName && hayCategory && hayAutor == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where nombre Like '%" + bookName + "%'" + " and idCategoria = " + idCategory;

            //hay autor y categoria pero no hay nombre de libro
            else if (hayAutor && hayCategory && hayBookName == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where idAutor = " + idAutor + " and idCategoria = " + idCategory;

            //si solo hay nombre de libro
            else if (hayBookName && hayAutor == false && hayCategory == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where nombre Like '%" + bookName +"%'";

            //si solo hay actor
            else if (hayAutor && hayBookName == false && hayCategory == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where idAutor = " + idAutor;

            //si solo hay categoria
            else if (hayCategory && hayAutor == false && hayBookName == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros idCategoria = " + idCategory;
            else
                consulta = "";

            List<Libro> list = new List<Libro>();

            //hacer uan funcvion que reciba la consulta
            if (consulta == "")
            {
                list = ls.ListBooks();
                return View(list);
            }
            else
            {
                list = ls.filtrarLibro(consulta);
                return View(list);
            }
```

Aca el Modelo

```html
public class Libro
    {
        public int IdLibro { get; set; }
        public String Nombre { get; set; }
        public int AnioDeLanzamiento { get; set; }
        public int IdAutor { get; set; }
        public int IdCategoria { get; set; }
        public int IdEditorial { get; set; }
        public String Descripcion { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public float Precio { get; set; }
        public String UrlImagen { get; set; }
        public bool Estado { get; set; }//si da error ponelo como int Mysql creo q toma False=0 y true=1

        public Libro()
        {
            //constructor vacio
        }

        public Libro(int idLibro, String nombre, int anioDeLanzamiento, int idAutor, int idCategoria, int idEditorial,
            String descripcion, int cantidad, float precio, String urlImagen, int estado)
        {

            IdLibro = idLibro;
            Nombre = nombre;
            AnioDeLanzamiento = anioDeLanzamiento;
            IdAutor = idAutor;
            IdCategoria = idCategoria;
            IdEditorial = idEditorial;
            Descripcion = descripcion;
            Cantidad = cantidad;
            Precio = precio;
            UrlImagen = urlImagen;
            this.Estado = Estado;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hola, indica en la pregunta el código del Controlador, el Modelo y lo que tienes en la directiva @model de la Vista.

Comment: Gracias Rafael!, ahí agregue los cambios.

Comment: Estas retornando solo una lista siempre, puedes leer los datos del nombre del libro y el autor que ingreso el usuario y pasarlos en un viewbag. En la vista revisas si no son nulas o en blanco les cargas en sus respectivos inputs

Comment: Gracias @DavElsanto me ayudó lo que dijiste, pensé que había que hacer algo con !IsPostBack o algo similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LO SOLUCIONE DE ESTA MANERA:

al código del controlador le agregue las `ViewBag` para capturar lo que el usuario escribió en los `input` del `formulario`.
Aca el controlador:

```html
public ActionResult userListarLibros()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            ViewBag.Email = Request.Form["email"];
            //Declaracion de las ViewBag***********
            ViewBag.Autor = "";
            ViewBag.NombreLibro = "";
            ViewBag.Categoria = "";
            ViewBag.IdAut = "";
            ViewBag.IdCat = "";
            LibroService ls = new LibroService();//es lo mismo
            AutorService sa = new AutorService();
            CategoriaService sc = new CategoriaService();
            bool hayBookName = false;
            bool hayAutor = false;
            bool hayCategory = false;
            String consulta = "";

            //guardando lo que el usuario escribio en los input text del form en variables
            String bookName = Request.Form["bookName"];
            String autor = Request.Form["ddlAutor"];
            String cat = Request.Form["ddlCategory"];

            int idAutor = 0;
            int idCategory = 0;

            if (bookName != null)
            {
                //guardo en la ViewBag el nombre del libro que escribio el usuario en el input text
                ViewBag.NombreLibro = Request.Form["bookName"];
                hayBookName = true;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(autor))
            {
                hayAutor = true;
                idAutor = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlAutor"]);
                //guardo en las ViewBag de autor el "autor" elegido x el usuario en el input text del form
                Autor aut = sa.getAutor(idAutor);
                ViewBag.Autor = aut.Nombre;
                ViewBag.IdAut = idAutor;              
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cat))
            {
                hayCategory = true;
                idCategory = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlCategory"]);
                //guardo en las VieBag de categoria, la categoria elegida x el usuario en el input text del form
                Categoria cate = sc.getCategoria(idCategory);
                ViewBag.Categoria = cate.Nombre;
                ViewBag.IdCat = idCategory;               
            }

            // hay nombre de libro autor y categoria
            if (hayBookName && hayAutor && hayCategory)
                consulta = "select * from libros where nombre Like '%" + bookName + "%'" + " and idAutor = " + idAutor + " and idCategoria = " + idCategory;

            //hay nombre de libro y autor pero no hay categoria
            else if (hayBookName && hayAutor && hayCategory == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where nombre Like '%" + bookName + "%'" + " and idAutor = " + idAutor;

            //hay nombre de libro y categoria pero no hay autor
            else if (hayBookName && hayCategory && hayAutor == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where nombre Like '%" + bookName + "%'" + " and idCategoria = " + idCategory;

            //hay autor y categoria pero no hay nombre de libro
            else if (hayAutor && hayCategory && hayBookName == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where idAutor = " + idAutor + " and idCategoria = " + idCategory;

            //si solo hay nombre de libro
            else if (hayBookName && hayAutor == false && hayCategory == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where nombre Like '%" + bookName + "%'";

            //si solo hay actor
            else if (hayAutor && hayBookName == false && hayCategory == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros where idAutor = " + idAutor;

            //si solo hay categoria
            else if (hayCategory && hayAutor == false && hayBookName == false)
                consulta = "select * from libros idCategoria = " + idCategory;
            else
                consulta = "";

            List<Libro> list = new List<Libro>();

            //si la consulta esta vacia trae todos los libros sin hacer filtro
            if (consulta == "")
            {
                list = ls.ListBooks();
                return View(list);
            }
            else
            {
                list = ls.filtrarLibro(consulta);
                return View(list);
            }

        }
```

y después En la `View` pregunto si esas `ViewBag` no están vacías, si es verdadero le asigno el valor de las `ViewBag`a los `input`.
Aca el `form` de la `View.cshtml`

```html
@model List<Librery_MVC.Models.Libro>

@using (Html.BeginForm("userListarLibros", "Usser", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Nombre de libro</label>

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.NombreLibro))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("bookName", (string)ViewBag.NombreLibro, new { @class = "form-control inputFiltros", id = "txtBuscar", value = @ViewBag.NombreLibro, placeholder = "Ingrese nombre del libro", maxlength = "80" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.TextBox("bookName", "", new { @class = "form-control inputFiltros", id = "txtBuscar", placeholder = "Ingrese nombre del libro", maxlength = "80" })
    }


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Autor</label>
        <select name="ddlAutor" class="form-control inputFiltros" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">

            @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Autor))
            {
                <option value=@ViewBag.IdAut>@ViewBag.Autor</option>
                <option></option>
                foreach (Autor item in autorList)
                {
                    <option value=@item.IdAutor>@item.Nombre</option>
                }

            }
            else
            {
                <option></option>
                foreach (Autor item in autorList)
                {
                    <option value=@item.IdAutor>@item.Nombre</option>
                }
            }

        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Categoria</label>
        <select name="ddlCategory" class="form-control inputFiltros" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
            @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Categoria))
            {
                <option value=@ViewBag.IdCat>@ViewBag.Categoria</option>
                <option></option>
                foreach (Categoria item in categoryList)
                {
                    <option value=@item.IdCategoria>@item.Nombre</option>
                }

            }
            else
            {
                <option></option>
                foreach (Categoria item in categoryList)
                {
                    <option value=@item.IdCategoria>@item.Nombre</option>
                }
            }

        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default inputFiltros" value="Filtrar" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Lo mejor es que esos valores no viajen hacia el servidor porque solo sirven para el lado del cliente, usa localstorage javascript del lado del navegador y asi no pierdes valores al recargar.

Comment: Gracias @Miguel Zarate es que no se hacerlo de la manera que me aconsejas, como seria?

Answer (score 1):

Te agrego un ejemplo, ya solo cambiarias los eventos de los botones,
cargarDatos, limpiarDatos, guardarDatos en tu pagina dependiendo si es un postback o no.

Por falta de tiempo solo storeTblValues, esta finalizada la implementacion. Si revisas el localStorage en tu aplicacion veras que los datos se guardan en formato json.
Como tarea ya solo con los valores recuperados en setTblValues() agrega a cada columna su respectivo valor.

```js
function storeTblValues()
{
    var TableData = new Array();

    $('#sampleTbl tr').each(function(row, tr){
        TableData[row]={
            "taskNo" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
            ,"date" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
            ,"description" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
            ,"task" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
        }    
    }); 
    TableData.shift();  // removiendo el primer renglon
 var   jsonTableData = $.toJSON(TableData);
 //guuardando en local storage.
 localStorage.setItem("tableData", jsonTableData);
}

function clearTable()
{
 //limpia el contenido de tu tabla
  $('#sampleTbl tr').html("")
}

function setTblValues()
{
 var dataTable = localStorage.getItem("tableData");
 dataTable= json_decode($tableData,TRUE);
 //TODO por implementar carga de datos en tabla
// dataTable.each()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-json/2.6.0/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
<div >
<table border="1" id="sampleTbl" width="515">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th align="center" width="20">
    Task No.</th>
   <th width="150">
    Date</th>
   <th width="170">
    Description</th>
   <th width="170">
    Task</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="center">
    1</td>
   <td>
    December 24, 2012</td>
   <td>
    Christmas Eve</td>
   <td>
    Make dinner</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center">
    2</td>
   <td>
    January 11, 2013</td>
   <td>
    Anniversary</td>
   <td>
    Pickup flowers</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center">
    3</td>
   <td>
    March 7, 2013</td>
   <td>
    Birthday</td>
   <td>
    Get present</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onClick="storeTblValues()">Guardar</button>
<button onClick="clearTable()">Limpiar tabla</button>
<button onClick="setTblValues()">Cargar datos</button>
```

Ahora en tu metodo los datos los guardaras cuando sea un postback y cuando sea
una carga inicial y si existen datos estos se pintan en la tabla.

Comment: Gracias @Miguel Zarate!